# Returning to my app after navigation

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

As suggested in other posts I used the following code to start navigation from my GDK application.  When the user finishes navigating they go back to the main "Ok Glass" screen.  Is there any way to bring the user back to my app?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+lat+","+lon));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but can you try adding the following flag to your intent and see if it changes the behavior?

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Can you please file an issue on our issue tracker so we can look into it further? https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list